# How to typeset a group of elements with common label?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-heading

In Bootstrap 3 HTML, how to set a group of elements with common label?

I want a visual rectangle to place inside it several HTML elements, in order to visually group these elements. There must be a label associated with the rectangle.

That is, I need to typeset a rectangle with a label (such as "project admin area") of this rectangle.

This may look like this:

```
/--Label-----------\
|                  |
\------------------/
```

(Elements which I put inside the rectangle omitted for graphics simplicity.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be simple but this works...

```
`
<div>
  <p>My Label</p>
</div>

<style>
div {
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 0px;}

p {
 background-color: #fff;
 margin: -10px 0px 0px 15px;
 width: 70px;}
</style>
```